# Two flask apps (models) using same table

Tags: flask, orm, mongoengine, flask-restful

I build 2 flask Apps App1 and App2(Two different services). Both Apps are referring to the same DB. Am using MongoDB as database and MongoEngine to create connections and to support ORM Queries.

I have created a user table in App1 and I defined the structure of the table in models.py file. Now I have to use the same user table in the App2. How would I use the existing table itself without rewriting the same code in APP2?

I can do it in one way that I can write a Mongo wrapper which will connect and serve the data. But I don't want to write RAW queries. Can someone help me how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your database-related code into a separate [Python package](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/) which both your applications can then import.

OR

You could also consider building a separate application around your database code that exposes information through an API. Your other applications could then make requests to this API.